# Any Good Sendfriend Event Dispatch in Magento?

Tags: magento

Looking for a decent observer of the Mage_Sendfriend module, when the product is sent to a friend.  I just traced it and don't see anything immediately useful.  There is one dispatch written in the module, which actually fires when the send to friend form is loaded, not when it's actually submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the events triggered, here are some events you might use:

```
controller_action_postdispatch_sendfriend_product_sendmail
controller_action_postdispatch_sendfriend
controller_action_postdispatch
```

And in the function you want to use for this event:

```
$controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
... your code here
```

Comment: I'm gonna accept this as the answer, b/c to my knowledge it's the only solution that doesn't require a rewrite - although as @JMTyler mentioned, this solution has modularity issues of it's own.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to resort to observing the `model_save_after` and `model_save_before` events, then checking `$observer->getEvent()->getObject()` to see if it's the Mage_Sendfriend model you're looking for.

An ugly solution, but sometimes the events just don't line up to solve a problem nicely.

Good luck!  Let us know if you find anything good!

***Edit:** I would also suggest against observing a controller for this, though, since that isn't very modular.  If a third-party module provides another interface for the Sendfriend feature, it wouldn't work with your module if you observe controller actions.*

Comment: This was what I was initially hoping to find, but believe it or not I actually don't even see one of those firing!  I'm looking in CE 1.7.0.0 at the moment.

Comment: @sparcksoft I don't mean a model-specific event, I mean precisely: `model_save_after`. This event gets dispatched by every single model, then you need to check the type of the model.

Comment: @FlorinelChis Yes, but extensibility and modularity is much more valuable than a minor amount of overhead. Since we're building on Magento, let's take a page out of Magento's book. Magento is _all about_ modules. If the feature doesn't work with other modules, it is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @JMTyler, so what I meant was there's actually not any `save()` being called within the module at all.  Weird, right?  Maybe this is specific to 1.7.0.0 - I might be able to figure out a creative way to hook a `model_load_after` though.

Comment: @sparcksoft model_save_after is generic, not model specific. Take a look at Mage_Core_Model_Abstract and `Mage::dispatchEvent` as an alternative... there is a second call to `Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_load_before', $params);`

Comment: @FlorinelChis I understand that :)  I don't know why it's not getting across that I understand the `model_save_after` event, as well as the other generic `model_*` events within `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` :)  It's not being dispatched though b/c there is no `save()`ing going on at all in the module.

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch custom events when and where you want.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('any_name_for_your_custom_event',
array('key'=>$value,'key'=>$value,'key'=>$value)); //can pass how many values you want in this array.
```

And in your config you just make your nodes to look for this event, and call one method from observer.
Its simple.

Comment: Hey @Guerra, thanks.  So what I'm looking for is an *existing* event dispatch within the Mage_Sendfriend module that I can observe.  I don't want to create a new event dispatch b/c that would mean modifying core, right?

Comment: @sparcksoft yeah sure, this would mean modifying core becouse you need put the dispatcher code to work. i understand you look for existing event. and FlorinelsChis already speak. i just say to comun sense know ;)