# Which event call on submitting "Send to Friend" Form in magento?

Tags: magento, events

I want to perform some actions when user submit "Send product link to friend" form, but i have issue in correct event, I used
 
 
....


this event call when user click on "Email to friend" link.. My need is to call event when user submit form..
Is there any event for such purpose ???
thanks in advance

Comment: i got the solution on the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359407/any-good-sendfriend-event-dispatch-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

As for my knowledge there is no event after submitting the the form.

But you can do it by
`preDispatch()` and `postDispatch()` methods

this link may be useful for you : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12341/are-there-events-for-those-2-actions

Cheers :-)